# GTKmm 3: Parse command line with Gtk::Application

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm trying to use GTK's argv-handling, but there seem to be some issues with the main loop.

My goal is to parse the command line after GTK removed its options (like `--display`), but before opening a window, because I want my app to be usable with a CLI-only interface, too, with both variants making use of Glib etc. This is why I'm trying to open the window in the `command_line` signal handler.

This works as expected, exits when the window is closed.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "my.app");
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow win;
    return app->run(win);
}
```

But simply adding the `HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE` flag destroys that: The window is never shown.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int on_cmd(const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::ApplicationCommandLine> &) {
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "my.app",
                 Gio::APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE);
    app->signal_command_line().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(on_cmd), false);
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow win;
    return app->run(win);
}
```

So I figured that the `command_line` handler isn't actually suppposed to return? But the documentation says `run` starts the main loop. I haven't found a method that simply waits for the main loop to finish, so I crank it manually. The window is being shown again, but of course the loop continues once it's closed, which is the least problem with that code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int on_cmd(const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::ApplicationCommandLine> &,
           Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> &app) {
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow win(app);
    // app->run(win); --- lands here again -> stack overflow.
    win.show();
    // This looks very wrong but seems to work?!
    while(true)
        Glib::MainContext::get_default()->iteration(true);
    // never reach this
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "my.app",
                 Gio::APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE);
    app->signal_command_line().connect(
      sigc::bind(sigc::ptr_fun(on_cmd), app), false);
    return app->run();
}
```

(gtkmm-3.0 version 3.5.13)

Comment: any particular reason why you don't just parse the incoming options first? From the way I understand it, gtk is just supposed to read your command line in case a gtk parse-able switch was thrown; it isn't supposed to clean it (again, from what I understand). I think libboost has a decent command line parsing class.

Comment: GTK removes specific options before emitting the `command_line`-signal, i.e. `./a.out --display :0 --foo` reaches the handler as `./a.out --foo` (and if the display is invalid, the program terminates with a GTK generated error message). Glib comes with `OptionContext` to parse the command line, and the now deprecated `Gtk::Main` class had direct support for it, too. The newer `Gtk::Application` has not, for some reason (are they trying to deprecate command line options altogether?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out, the key is calling `activate` on the application. The default handler which is executed when `HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE` is not given does that automatically.

My second example was just missing one line:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int on_cmd(const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::ApplicationCommandLine> &,
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> &app) {
    app->activate(); // <----
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "my.app",
                 Gio::APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE);
    app->signal_command_line().connect(
      sigc::bind(sigc::ptr_fun(on_cmd), app), false);
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow win;
    return app->run(win);
}
```

Here's a subclassed application which parses the command line using Glib, and if `--gui` is present, opens a window and only terminates after the window is closed.

Using `gtk_get_option_group` adds the GTK options (and help) to it, so `--help-all` really shows all applicable options, and we don't have to rely on `gtk_main(argc, argv)` to remove the GTK options, i.e. the argments can be deferred to the `run(argc, argv)` call (but don't have to. If the application constructor is given the arguments, it will remove the GTK options, except `--help-gtk`, our handler just never sees them but can still display help for it. Doesn't seem to matter either way)

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
struct MyApp : Gtk::Application {
    MyApp() : Gtk::Application("my.app",
      Gio::APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE) {}
    int on_command_line(const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::ApplicationCommandLine> &cmd) {
        // parse arguments:
        Glib::OptionContext ctx;
        Glib::OptionGroup group("options", "main options");
        bool show_gui = false;
        Glib::OptionEntry entry;
        entry.set_long_name("gui");
        entry.set_description("show the gui.");
        group.add_entry(entry, show_gui);
        ctx.add_group(group);
        // add GTK options, --help-gtk, etc
        Glib::OptionGroup gtkgroup(gtk_get_option_group(true));
        ctx.add_group(gtkgroup);
        int argc;
        char **argv = cmd->get_arguments(argc);
        ctx.parse(argc, argv);
        // maybe show the gui
        if(show_gui)
            activate();
        return 0;
    }
    Gtk::ApplicationWindow *main;
    void on_activate() {
        // can't use Gtk::manage, so we have to keep
        // the reference or the main loop quits.
        main = new Gtk::ApplicationWindow();
        add_window(*main);
        main->show();
    }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return MyApp().run(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue and if we use args , then we have to use additional flags, https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/gtkmm-tutorial.html